# Page Scroll View Help, different views controllers each page?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

Ok, so I am trying to a pagescrollView with two views each with a different view controller so I can work on each different view. I got apple's sample code and it seems that they created a lot of different view "lazily as they said" how can this code be altered so that I can have the first page be one view controller and the second page be another view controller?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    // view controllers are created lazily
    // in the meantime, load the array with placeholders which will be replaced on demand
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++) {
        [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    self.viewControllers = controllers;
    [controllers release];

    // a page is the width of the scroll view
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    pageControl.numberOfPages = kNumberOfPages;
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;

    // pages are created on demand
    // load the visible page
    // load the page on either side to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];
}

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    MyViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    // We don't want a "feedback loop" between the UIPageControl and the scroll delegate in
    // which a scroll event generated from the user hitting the page control triggers updates from
    // the delegate method. We use a boolean to disable the delegate logic when the page control is used.
    if (pageControlUsed) {
        // do nothing - the scroll was initiated from the page control, not the user dragging
        return;
    }
    // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;

    // load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];

    // A possible optimization would be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible
}

// At the end of scroll animation, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pageControlUsed = NO;
}

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    int page = pageControl.currentPage;
    // load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];
    // update the scroll view to the appropriate page
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    // Set the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl. See scrollViewDidScroll: above.
    pageControlUsed = YES;
}
```

Thanks if anyone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 6):

To load the pages with different view controllers all you have to change is this segment of code

```
MyViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page]; 
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) 
{ controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page]; 
[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
 [controller release]; 
}
```

to initialize each view controller to the one  you want  instead of the same one each time, so the code would look something  like

```
 if(page==0)
{
 MyViewControllerZero *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page]; 
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) 
    { controller = [[MyViewControllerZero alloc] initWithPageNumber:page]; 
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
     [controller release]; 
    }
}
  if(page==1)
{
 MyViewControllerOne *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page]; 
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) 
    { controller = [[MyViewControllerOne alloc] initWithPageNumber:page]; 
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
     [controller release]; 
    }
}
//and so on ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the Correct Code!!!

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
if (page < 0) return;
if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;

// replace the placeholder if necessary
if (page == 0){
MyViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
    controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];

}
    if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
}
}
if (page == 1){
    PageOne *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        controller = [[PageOne alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];

    }
    if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
}
// add the controller's view to the scroll view

}
```

}

THX For the first answewr she open my mind!!!